# Div doesn't stretch to window height

Tags: html, css

I have issues with a div that has to stay 100% of window height. Once I place another div inside of it that exceeds screen size, parent div doesn't stretch after its child. Here is my code:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="mainframe">
            <div class="screencontainer">
                <div class="mainscreen"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is css:

```
html,body {
    background:white;
    height:100%;
    margin: 0px 0px;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}


.mainframe{
    background:green;   
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:100%;
    overflow:none;

}

.screencontainer{
    background:red;
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    overflow:none;
    width:60%;
    left:250px; 
}

.mainscreen{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:1000px;
    top:100px;
    left:0px;
    background: radial-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.0),rgba(0,0,0,0.5));
}
```

So .mainframe is 100% of window size only if I remove .screencontainer with all its content. But once I have it, because its child .mainscreen has 1000px height, mainframe breaks in the middle of a page.

Here is jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/u4oL7t80/

Comment: create some jsfiddle code and add it will help a lot to understand the question and problem

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/u4oL7t80/

Comment: ok now you want `<div class="mainscreen">` to stretch to 100% or `<div class="screencontainer">` to be 100%

Comment: I need .mainframe to keep at 100% height of the window. At the moment it breaks in the middle for some reason. So I need background to stay green.

Comment: @NebularDust there is no value `none` for the `overflow` property. **[MDN Docs - overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)**

Comment: @NebularDust you want that your background is always 100% stretched? on any screen resolution? is that it?

Comment: Not body background, but mainframe div.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the [`overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) setting of the `.mainframe` from `none` (which is an illegitimate value) to `scroll`.

[jsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/u4oL7t80/1/)

That way the container itself (`.mainframe`) will not stretch, but have its own scrollbar.

You can also set [`overflow-y`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-y) instead, to allow only a vertical scrollbar.

Comment: Thank you that fixed the thing!